# Extracting a value from a fields XML?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

(Using SQL Server 2016 standard)

I my table "Persons", I have an NVARCHAR(MAX) field called "Log".

This is a sample of what can be in that log:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<ArrayOfLogItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <LogItem>
        <OldValue xsi:type="xsd:decimal">40</OldValue>
        <NewValue xsi:type="xsd:decimal">41</NewValue>
        <FieldName>age</FieldName>
    </LogItem>
    <LogItem>
        <OldValue xsi:type="xsd:decimal">2000</OldValue>
        <NewValue xsi:type="xsd:decimal">2100</NewValue>
        <FieldName>salary</FieldName>
    </LogItem>
    <LogItem>
        <OldValue xmlns:q1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xsi:type="q1:guid">e5e6aa24-4f2f-437d-bf16-21724e9c61b2</OldValue>
        <NewValue xmlns:q2="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xsi:type="q2:guid">370cee00-f51a-4bf0-a8bf-c0f1de025a0a</NewValue>
        <FieldName>user_ID</FieldName>
    </LogItem>
</ArrayOfLogItem>
```

I need to figure out, if the log field has the row with the fieldname "salary" - and if so, I need to extract the old value (2000) and the new value (2100).

Is that possible?

This is how far I've reached...

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<ArrayOfLogItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <LogItem>
        <OldValue xsi:type="xsd:decimal">40</OldValue>
        <NewValue xsi:type="xsd:decimal">41</NewValue>
        <FieldName>age</FieldName>
    </LogItem>
    <LogItem>
        <OldValue xsi:type="xsd:decimal">2000</OldValue>
        <NewValue xsi:type="xsd:decimal">2100</NewValue>
        <FieldName>salary</FieldName>
    </LogItem>
    <LogItem>
        <OldValue xmlns:q1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xsi:type="q1:guid">e5e6aa24-4f2f-437d-bf16-21724e9c61b2</OldValue>
        <NewValue xmlns:q2="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xsi:type="q2:guid">370cee00-f51a-4bf0-a8bf-c0f1de025a0a</NewValue>
        <FieldName>user_ID</FieldName>
    </LogItem>
</ArrayOfLogItem>'

SELECT   ???
```

...and I'm stuck.

Any idea if it is possible?

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT a.b.value('OldValue[1]', 'varchar(255)'), a.b.value('NewValue[1]', 'varchar(255)') FROM @xml.nodes('ArrayOfLogItem/LogItem') a(b) WHERE a.b.value('FieldName[1]', 'varchar(255)') = 'salary';`. I would suggest googling how to use XML in SQL Server.

Comment: You can also use `IF @xml.exist('/ArrayOfLogItem/LogItem/FieldName[text()="salary"]') = 1` to check if the log field has the row with the fieldname "salary" and perform your required operation